having problems displaying Alert on SwipeListView swipe left
The following code displays a list of cards where each card represents an article summary.  I've implemented SwipeListView based on feedback from ChatGPT.  When a user swipes left on the card, I want the screen to display an Alert that says "Are you sure that you want to Delete this article?"
Currently a user is able to swipe the card left as expected - but the alert does not display.  I've taken this through a few iterations with ChatGPT and Gemini but neither of them seems to be able to fix the issue.  Looks like this is one of those issues where I need some help from a real human React Native developer.  Can you provide any insight on this?  I copied the component code to codesandbox at the url below:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/article-manager-tj5gk5?file=%2Fsrc%2FArticleManager.jsx%3A5%2C31

Use negative values for rightOpenValue.

TranslateX value for opening the row to the right (negative number)

Something like this:
<SwipeListView
  data={articles}
...
  rightOpenValue={-75}
  disableRightSwipe={true}
...
/>

